# How to run multiple instances of the same class asynchrously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I'm looking to have many agents connect to different sockets of my local server so they can independently read and send to the server. So far I have this:

```py
import json
import asyncio

class Agent():
    def __init__(self, user, pw):
        self.user = user
        self.pw = pw

        # Store host and port
        self.host, self.port = "localhost", 12300

        self.connect()

    async def connect(self):
        # Create asynchronous socket reader and writer
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host,
                                                                 self.port)

        request = <some_json>

        # Create and send authentication request
        self.writer.write(request)
        await self.writer.drain()

        response = await self.reader.read(1000)
        response = json.loads(response.decode().split("\0")[0])

        if response["content"]["result"] == "ok":
            print("Connection Succesful")
        else:
            print("Connection Failed")

        await self.listen()

    async def receive_msg(self):
        """
        Waits for a message from the server and returns it.
        """
        msg = await self.reader.readuntil(b"\0")
        msg = msg.decode().split("\0")[0]

        # In case a message is received, parse it into a dictionary.
        if len(msg) > 1:

            return json.loads(msg)
        else:
            print("Retry receiving message...")
            return self.receive_msg()

    async def listen(self):
        """
        Listens for output from server and writes if anything is received
        """

        while True:
            msg = await self.receive_msg()
            print("Message received", self.user)


a_list = []

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

for i in range(15):
    a_list.append(Agent(f"agentA{i}", "1").connect())

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*a_list))
```

Because of the way asyncio works I think this is the only way to run this asynchrously. But I would like to be able to make the `__init__` run asynchrously somehow instead of having to throw the `connect` function into the loop if that is possible. What I essentially would like to do is this:

```py
a_list = []

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

for i in range(15):
    a_list.append(Agent(f"agentA{i}", "1"))

loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*a_list))
```

I think that that makes more sense, but I can't figure out how to do it. Am I thinking wrongly, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There is no way to make `__init__` asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make `__init__` async, but you *can* make `Agent` instances awaitable. To do so, define the `__await__` magic method:

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, user, pw):
        self.user = user
        self.pw = pw
        self.host, self.port = "localhost", 12300

    def __await__(self):
        yield from self.connect().__await__()
```

This has the best of both worlds: your `__init__` function remains sync, and yet `Agent` instances are valid arguments to functions like `asyncio.gather()`.

Comment: This is almost what I'm looking for, but I don't necesarrility want to make the connect function the backbone of the agent if you undertand what I mean. I would like to make the entire agent "awaitable" if that makes sense. If it doesn't, that is fine, I'm extremely new to asynchronous programming.

Comment: @PEREZje You can await whatever you want inside `__await__`, it doesn't need to be `connect`. You can have some logic that awaits this or that depending on the state of the object, and so on. Either way, await is a transitive verb, so you have to await _something_, you can't just generally "make it available" without deciding, somewhere, what it is it's awaiting.

Comment: I've looked into it and you are right, thanks so much for the help